# Minio InvalidEndpointError: Invalid endPoint

Tags: node.js, minio

I have a host - 192.168.200.xx1 where Minio runs in Docker. I launched minio with this command - `docker run --name minio_server --hostname minio -d -p 9000:9000 -p 9001:9001 minio/minio server /data --console-address ":9001"` . So, I have another host 192.168.200.xx2 with NodeJS code from whom I try to send data to minio. This is my NodeJS code:

```
async function uploadImage(req, res) {
    const path = await image_functions_1.ImageLoad.urlCreate(userId, surveyId) + "/" + req.file.originalname;
        return res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: "Failed to upload!" });
    let minioClient = new Minio.Client({
        endPoint: process.env.MINIO_END_POINT,
        port: 9000,
        useSSL: false,
        accessKey: process.env.MINIO_ACCESS_KEY,
        secketKey: process.env.MINIO_SECRET_KEY
    });
    minioClient.putObject(process.env.MINIO_BUCKET, path, req.file.buffer, function (err, etag) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

The trouble comes when I try to send data fom data fom JS to Minio, there is the following error:

```
(node:14441) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: InvalidEndpointError: Invalid endPoint : http://192.168.200.xx1
    at new Client (/home/moxem/backend/node_modules/minio/dist/main/minio.js:102:13)
    at uploadImage (/home/moxem/backend/dist/api/Media/image_crud.js:34:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

The value of endPoint in .env file is: `MINIO_END_POINT=http://192.168.xxx.xx1` .
Also, I tried to change the value to the hostname of the minio: `MINIO_END_POINT=minio://192.168.200.xx1`. But the same error raised.
Also in host 192.168.200.xx1 I opened minio port by `sudo ufw allow 9000`. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the resulting client configuration should be like

```js
// so http:// needs to be removed from endpoint.


var s3Client = new Minio.Client({
  useSSL: false,
  endPoint: "localhost",
  port: 9000,
  accessKey: "minio",
  secretKey: "minio123"
})

//with hosted play instance.
let s3Client  =new Minio.Client({
  endPoint: 'play.min.io',
  port: 9000,
  useSSL: true,
  accessKey: 'Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F',
  secretKey: 'zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG'
})
```

so `http://`  needs to be removed from endpoint.